# gsoap undefined reference after successfully generating c++ code

Tags: c++, gsoap, undefined-reference

I'm trying to use gsoap-generated code to use an ASP .NET webservice from C++ sources from a linux system.

I successfully created code from my wsdl-file using "wsdl2h -o" and "soapcpp2 -C -i" and am now trying to compile a simple client

According to the soap documentation I now tried to compile a simple client:
Trying to compile it using:

```
c++ -o vts_webservice vts_webservice.cpp -lgsoap
```

I get undefined reference errors:
Sourcecode:

```
#include "soapBasicHttpBinding_USCORECollectorServiceProxy.h"
#include "BasicHttpBinding_USCORECollectorService.nsmap"

int main()
{
        BasicHttpBinding_USCORECollectorServiceProxy collectorService;
        _ns1__GetAvailableConnections *avConn;
        _ns1__GetAvailableConnectionsResponse *avConnResp;

        if(collectorService.GetAvailableConnections(avConn, avConnResp) == SOAP_OK)
        {
                std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
        }
        else
                std::cout << "bar..." << std::endl;
                //collectorService.soap_stream_fault(std::cerr);

        return 0;
}
```

> c++ -o vts_webservice vts_webservice.cpp -lgsoap tmp cc3uVBgk.o(.text+0x1e): In function `main': : undefined reference
>   to`
>   BasicHttpBinding_USCORECollectorServiceProxy::BasicHttpBinding_USCORECollectorServiceProxyin-charge'
>    tmp cc3uVBgk.o(.text+0x40): In function `main': : undefined reference
>   to`
>   BasicHttpBinding_USCORECollectorServiceProxy::GetAvailableConnections(*ns1*_GetAvailableConnections*,
>   *ns1*_GetAvailableConnectionsResponse*)' tmp-cc3uVBgk.o(.text+0x9c): In function `main': : undefined reference to`
>   BasicHttpBinding_USCORECollectorServiceProxy::~BasicHttpBinding_USCORECollectorServiceProxy

Does anyone have any aproaches on this? I would be very thankful for any hints!

Many thanks in advance, 
meph

P.S.: This hyperlink limitation is BLOODY annoying! I don't have ANY hyperlinks in my posting, JUST linux-filesystem-paths. ARGH!

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain but it appears from what you have written that you have forgotten to include the soapC.cpp file in the compilation step?? When I build my apps I usually end up with something like

```
    g++ -FLAGS main.cpp soapC.cpp soapProxyClass.cpp -o outputApp
```

Maybe you are already doing this but was not obvious (to me at least) from your post.